# how to store data with generic types in an Java arraylist

Tags: java

I will try my best to explain my problem and hopefully someone can help me.

Pair class:

```
public class Pair {
   String key;
   Class<?> value;
   public Pair(String key, Class<?> value){
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
   };
   // you have the setter and getter methods
}
```

Pairs class:

```
public class Pairs {
   Pair[] paris = new Pair[0];
   // you have the setter and getter methods
   public void addPair(Pair pair) {
      // assume it will add a pair to the array
   }
}
```

Problem: I need to load data from a database table. The column types are different here. There are BOOLEAN, VARCHAR, DATE and others. So I need to read and store the data with corresponding java type into the Pair object. How do you convert from generic type to String or Boolean? And how do you do the other way around?

I found an answer for converting generic type to String:

```
Class<?> value = getValue();
if (value.isInstance(String.class))
String newValue = (String)(Object) value; // is it correct?
```

Then how can I convert a String to Class< ?> and store the data into the arraylist? Because I want to create:

```
Pair pair = new Pair("name", value); // but value can be String, Integer, or Boolean
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would just not do this; it looks horrible. Java is a strongly typed language, if you want a weakly typed language; use one. Further, your `value` is a `Class` not an instance of a `class`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider the snippets are not good, I agree, but when dealing with data such as Json or data from a database, there's always a certain amount of type unsafety when deserializing or decoding the data, regardless of the language type system

Comment: Why not define a class that represents your tuple? Instead of each column separately.

Comment: @Dici not in Java. If you're getting data from somewhere you know what that data is. If you do not; then how can you know what you want to do with it? In Java you would create objects to represent the data and then read the data into those. If you want to do this in a type unsafe way; use Groovy...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Stuff like `node.get(field).asInt()` are inherently unsafe (Jackson API). That's what I mean: parsing data is almost always unsafe. `ResultSet.getInt` is unsafe as well (Java standard library). Data has no type, the very fact of converting data to a Java object is unsafe. If the parsing succeeds you're good, but essentially you have no compile-time guarantee that this will work.

Comment: @BoristheSpider actually if I think about it the Json tree should be fully type-safe, it's just that Jackson exposes handy unsafe accessors. A type-safe code would imply to traverse the whole tree and constantly check the concrete type of the nodes? I guess that's a trade-off between type safety and usability

Comment: @Dici that is my point; to be useful data has a structure - this is of course typesafe. There are plenty of frameworks for specifying this structure, for example JSON schemas, and plenty of frameworks for writing code to bind this typesafe data to your class hierarchy. Obviously, when it comes to runtime - someone might feed you the wrong data...

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start, by making `Pair` generic. Something like,

```
public class Pair<T> {
   String key;
   T value;
   public Pair(String key, T value){
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
   };
   // ...
}
```

Then you instantiate a `Pair` for the correct column type. Like,

```
Pair<String> p = new Pair<>("a", "b");
```

**or**

```
Pair<Integer> p = new Pair<>("a", 1);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need =] thank you so much. Sorry for horrible codes like this. I am glad I find an answer here.